# Finding a modern derivation of the biserial correlation

Tags: correlation, references

Jacobs (2017) states a formula for the biserial correlation coefficient, citing Pearson's original (1909) paper. I find that old paper hard to read. Does anyone know of a modern derivation of the formula?

--

Jacobs, P., & Viechtbauer, W. (2017). Estimation of the biserial correlation and its sampling variance for use in meta-analysis. Research Synthesis Methods, 8(2), 161-180.

Pearson, K (1909). On a New Method of Determining Correlation Between a Measured Character A, and a Character B, of which Only the Percentage of Cases Wherein B Exceeds (or Falls Short of) a Given Intensity is Recorded for Each Grade of A. Biometrika Vol. 7, No. 1/2 (Jul. - Oct., 1909), pp. 96-105

Comment: One way to find the duplicate quickly is to search our site for keywords from your question: [point biserial coefficient Pearson correlation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22point+biserial+coefficient%22+pearson+correlation).

Comment: @whuber the biserial correlation coefficient is not the same thing as the point-biserial correlation coefficient. (That’s precisely what the Jacobs paper is about… )

Comment: Please explain the distinction.  I don't use these terms, because I find them too obscure, and my searches keep turning up references that appear to conflate "point biserial coefficient" and "biserial coefficient."

Comment: @whuber explanation in chat. (And, exactly the same search difficulty led me to ask the q.)